# How to use Magento 2 SOAP API from Python?

Tags: magento2, api, soap

I am trying to fetch all the orders and customer from Magento 2 to my python based application. But I am not able to get any API to use in Python.

Anyone who has used Magento 2 SOAP API in python, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly! Using Magento 2's SOAP API from Python can be done using the `zeep` library, which is a SOAP client for Python. Below is a step-by-step guide to fetch all the orders and customers from Magento 2 to your Python-based application using the SOAP API:

#### Pre-requisites:

1. Install the `zeep` library using pip:

```bash
pip install zeep
```

2. Ensure that you have set up API access in your Magento 2 instance and have the API key.

#### Steps:

1. **Setting up a SOAP client**:

```python
from zeep import Client

WSDL_URL = "http://YOUR_MAGENTO_DOMAIN/soap/default?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1"
client = Client(WSDL_URL)
```

2. **Retrieve the API Token**:
   Replace `YOUR_USERNAME` and `YOUR_PASSWORD` with your API credentials from Magento.

```python
credentials = {
    "username": "YOUR_USERNAME",
    "password": "YOUR_PASSWORD"
}
token = client.service.integrationAdminTokenServiceV1CreateAdminAccessToken(**credentials)
```

3. **Fetch Customers**:
   Now, create a new client for the `customerCustomerRepositoryV1` service and fetch the customers.

```python
CUSTOMER_WSDL_URL = "http://YOUR_MAGENTO_DOMAIN/soap/default?wsdl&services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1"
customer_client = Client(CUSTOMER_WSDL_URL)

# Set the required headers for the session
session_headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
}
customer_client.set_default_soapheaders(session_headers)

# Fetch customers
customers = customer_client.service.customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetList()

print(customers)
```

4. **Fetch Orders**:
   Similarly, create a client for the `salesOrderRepositoryV1` service and fetch the orders.

```python
ORDER_WSDL_URL = "http://YOUR_MAGENTO_DOMAIN/soap/default?wsdl&services=salesOrderRepositoryV1"
order_client = Client(ORDER_WSDL_URL)

# Set the required headers for the session
order_client.set_default_soapheaders(session_headers)

# Fetch orders
orders = order_client.service.salesOrderRepositoryV1GetList()

print(orders)
```

Note: Make sure to replace `YOUR_MAGENTO_DOMAIN`, `YOUR_USERNAME`, and `YOUR_PASSWORD` with appropriate values. Also, handle potential exceptions and add error checking as needed.

This should help you get started with using the Magento 2 SOAP API from Python. Depending on your specific requirements, you might need to adjust the above code or use other available SOAP services provided by Magento 2.